# When to use Generic Class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

There is an example from documentation, but it is not clear how to use in practice:

```
class Result<T> {
 constructor(public wasSuccessful: boolean, public error: T) {
 }
 public clone(): Result<T> {
 ...
 }
}
let r1 = new Result(false, 'error: 42');
```

Comment: When you have some generic functionality.

Comment: In you example clone must return a string.

Comment: @Vayrex that's not true. `clone` will return a `Result<string>`. In their example, what is useful about the type is that the `error` property will always be a string when you clone off of a `Result<string>`. You only get that guarantee with generic types.

Comment: Why? Can you explain benefits of this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you may have abstract class and collection which is working with T childs of that class.

```
abstract class BaseModel<T extends BaseModel<{}>>{
  abstract get(): any;
  abstract create(): any;
  abstract etc(): this;
}

class ProductModel extends BaseModel<ProductModel>{
  etc(){
    return this;
  }

  get(){
    console.log('Got somehing for product model');    
  }

  create(){
    console.log('Created something');
  }
}

class Service<T extends BaseModel<{}>>{

  constructor(private model: T){

  }

  getSomething(){
    return this.model.get();
  }
}

let service = new Service(new ProductModel());

service.getSomething();
```

UPDATE: as you was asking about example

```
abstract class BaseItem{

}

class Item extends BaseItem{

}

class OpenableItem extends BaseItem{

}

class MultiLineItem extends BaseItem{

}

class Menu<T extends BaseItem>{
  private items: T[];  
}
```

It may be possible to use interface Item and do separate classes for each item, but if there are same functions, you it may be better to use abstract class.

Comment: Whats is benefit of this? Why I can not use regular class?

Comment: You can use regular class, but if you need type validation and have generic functionality for types passed to class or function, you need to use generics. 
Sometimes you may have number of types. So you may say that some collection can receive just classes which implements some interface.

Comment: I can not fell this in real life (:

Comment: When I meet generics it was hard to place in head all that logic.

Comment: You need to see some courses about TDD/Architecture, or read some books. In real life parts of business logic are divided by framework and most part of developers are using ready classes, so they have not a need to use own generic functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather abstract question and one that is hard to answer appropriately without knowing you level of experience with programming and with general object oriented concepts.

Perhaps the simplest useful generic type around that exists in TypeScript as well as any other language with generic types, is the generically typed array or list.

There are a handful of operations that you can perform on an array without knowing the exact type it contains. A simple example of `Array.prototype.map` for example:

```
function map<T, R>(array: Array<T>, callback: (t: T) => R): Array<R> {
    const ret: Array<R> = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        // We can guarantee that the result of calling `callback`
        // will be an R, whatever R may be
        const cbResult: R = callback(array[i]);

        // Because we know it's an R, we can safely
        // push it into the array of R!
        ret.push(cbResult);
    }

    // Now the caller of the function has a guarantee that what
    // is returned from `map` is an Array of type R where R is
    // the result type of the callback
    return ret;
}

class Foo {
    constructor(public bar: string) { }
}

const stringArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const numberArray = [1, 2, 3];
const fooArray = [new Foo('hello'), new Foo('friend')];

// By using generic type parameters, we can guarantee the
// type safety of the callback functions
const numberArrayAsStrings: Array<string> = map<number, string>(numberArray, (num) => num.toString());

// Each one of these callbacks knows for a fact that the type T
// will be passed in and that they've promised to return the type R
const stringArrayAsUppercase: Array<string> = map<string, string>(stringArray, (letter) => letter.toUpperCase());

// When we do that, we can write functions like map that do
// complex operations on multiple different types of objects
const fooArrayAsBars: Array<string> = map<Foo, string>(fooArray, (foo) => foo.bar);
```

So when you call this implementation of `Array.prototype.map`, the implementation of the `map` function doesn't have to know what the Array contains, but you as the consumer get all the benefit of knowing that an element of type `T` will get passed into your callback and that an Array of type `R` will be returned as the result of calling `map`.

What this means, is that in their simplest usage, generics are useful to an API designer that is offering some abstract operation on a data model that usually contains the generic type. They are then useful to the consumer of the API because whatever operation the API offers is possible while you still maintain type safety in your client code.

With the example of the `map` function above, you can see that literally any kind of array can be mapped over to create a new type safe array of a resulting type using a callback function that itself is type safe.

---

Typically, generics are combined with interfaces to power specific operations on different types of objects. Forgive the long example! I'm not sure there's a good way to give a useful example that isn't rather lengthy.

```
interface IEquatable<T> {
    equals: (other: T) => boolean;
}

interface IComparable<T> extends IEquatable<T> {
    compare: (left: T, right: T) => 1 | 0 | -1;
}

class Bar implements IEquatable<Bar> {
    constructor(public bang: number) { }

    equals(right: Bar) {
        return this.bang === right.bang;
    }
}

class Baz implements IComparable<Baz> {
    constructor(public zim: number) { }

    compare(left: Baz, right: Baz) {
        if (left.zim > right.zim) return 1;
        else if (left.zim === right.zim) return 0;
        else return -1;
    }

    equals(other: Baz) {
        return this.compare(this, other) === 0;
    }
}

/**
 * Sort function that would rely on the result of calling compare
 * each element in the array to sort them according to the comparison
 */
function sort<T extends IComparable<T>>(array: Array<T>): Array<T> {
    // Saving space by not implementing this
    return array;
}

/**
 * Determines whether the arrays have the same contents by sorting
 * the arrays and then calling the arrayEqual function to see if the
 * sorted arrays are equal
 */
function arraySameContents<T extends IComparable<T>>(left: Array<T>, right: Array<T>): boolean {
    if (left.length !== right.length) return false;

    const sortedLeft = sort(left);
    const sortedRight = sort(right);

    return arrayEqual(sortedLeft, sortedRight);
}

/**
 * Compares each element in the left array to the element at the same
 * index in the right array, returning true if all elements are equal
 * and false otherwise
 */
function arrayEqual<T extends IEquatable<T>>(left: Array<T>, right: Array<T>): boolean {
    if (left.length !== right.length) return false;

    for (let i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
        if (!left[i].equals(right[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

As you can see, by using generic type parameters in our array comparison functions and in our interfaces, we can make guarantees about the types of arrays that can be compared without knowing a single thing about the objects being compared other than that they implement a `compare` or `equals` function! This is a relatively simple example of the power of generic programming. The RxJS framework is a great example of somewhere where generics really shine.

For a takeaway exercise: can you implement the `IEquatable` and `IComparable` interfaces on a class whose declaration looks roughly like this?

```
class EquatableArray<T> extends Array<T> implements IEquatable<T> {

}
```

A few questions to consider before beginning to write any code for this: Does the type parameter `T` need to have any restrictions? To be able write the `equals` functions for the `ComparableArray` do we need to know any extra information about `T`? What if we tried to use the functions we wrote before, `arrayEqual` and `arraySameContents`?

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, can you provide more real example from life? Or more frequency case?

Comment: Updated with a nice long example! Hopefully that helps. This is a real life example that is used all over the place in Java, C#, etc. to be able to compose big abstract data structures.